# Recursion locking (i.e. a lock that works on the same thread)

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I would like to have a lock that prevents a section of code from being entered from the *same* thread to make it more bulletproof from infinite recursion. That is, something like:

```
private static object RecurseLock = new object();
public void PartiallyRecursiveMethod()
{
    if (TryEnter(RecurseLock))
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello ");
            // we want to do it again now
            PartiallyRecursiveMethod();
        }
        finally
        {
            Release(RecurseLock);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("world!");
}
```

Such that the output from a call to `PartiallyRecursiveMethod` is "**Hello world!**". (or maybe there's a newline in there, I forget how `Console.WriteLine` works)

The TryEnter should only apply to the *current* thread. Other threads should not be blocked.

Is there something in C# that does this already or do I have to write my own? I believe all of the usual suspects (`Monitor.TryEnter`, `SemaphoreSlim` etc.) only obtain a lock that excludes *different* threads; using them here will just cause a stack overflow.

This needs to be within .NET 2.

I am aware, by the way, that this requirement indicates that the code is very bad and that really a code rewrite would be more sensible. I am nonetheless interested if .NET offers anything like this.

Comment: You can use the [`Semaphore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this.

Comment: @MatthewWatson From MSDN, it says: "A thread can enter the semaphore multiple times". Is there a specific implementation you had in mind?

Comment: A simple [`ThreadLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx) boolean will allow you to do this. No need for any lock mechanism.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That sounds right, unfortunately I need this to work in .NET 2 (forgot to mention). Will update the question.

Comment: @bommelding Yes I'm aware. However I am interested to know if anything is offered for this case regardless.

Comment: @Patrick See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016595/what-is-the-correct-way-to-prevent-reentrancy-and-ensure-a-lock-is-acquired-for). You need to specify a max count of 1 for the semaphore.

Comment: @bommelding No Just .NET 2 is right I believe.

Comment: Question is a bit unclear - does OP want to allow multiple threads to call the method simultaneously, while disallowing the same thread to call it reentrantly? And if the same thread DOES call it reentrantly, then the only recourse would be to return immediately without waiting. of course.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I am interested in both cases actually, but i will update the question.

Comment: Would a threadstatic boolean not do?

Comment: Yes, from the looks of it a thread-local boolean would solve this.

Comment: @bommelding I think in .NET2 it's called ThreadStaticAttribute, but thanks, this appears to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As several people have pointed out, in .Net 2.x you can use `[ThreadStatic]` for this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(test, test, test);
        }

        static void test()
        {
            if (_thisThreadAlreadyHere)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} is already working.");
                return;
            }

            _thisThreadAlreadyHere = true;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} is working.");

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                test();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} has completed.");
            }

            finally
            {
                _thisThreadAlreadyHere = false;
            }
        }

        [ThreadStatic]
        static bool _thisThreadAlreadyHere;
    }
}
```

However, I would say that trying to solve "infinite recursion" issues in this way is somewhat suspect. I would have thought that there should be a better way to fix the logic - this seems like a sticking plaster approach.

Comment: As a template, this should have a try finally to prevent the block being locked out for eternity if there's an exception. But thank you, `ThreadStatic` is what I am after.

Comment: @Patrick I added the try/finally in case anyone else uses this answer for anything.